# Ajax retornando [object Object]

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

**HTML**

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link href="css/refreshform.css" rel="stylesheet">

 </head>
<body>

 <div id="mainform">
  <h2>Submit Form Using AJAX and jQuery</h2> 
  <div id="form">
   <h3>Fill Your Information !</h3>
   <div>
    <label>Email :</label>
    <input id="email" type="text">
    <label>Password :</label>
    <input id="password" type="password">
    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

**script.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit").click(function(){
  var name   = $("#name").val();
  var email   = $("#email").val();
  var password  = $("#password").val();
  var contact  = $("#contact").val();

  var dataString = '&email1=' + email + '&password1=' + password;
   if(email == '' || password == '' )
   {
    alert("Por favor preencha todos campos");
   }
   else
   {
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://192.168.0.10/apps/ajaxsubmit.php",
     data: dataString,
     datatype: 'json',
      success: function(data){
       $('#result').html(data.status +':' + data.message);   
                $("#result").addClass('msg_notice');
                $("#result").fadeIn(1500);  
      }
    });
   }
  return false;
 });
});
```

**PHP**

**ajaxsubmit.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 

$db = mysql_select_db("mydba", $connection); 

$email2     =   $_POST['email1'];
$password2  =   $_POST['password1'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form_element WHERE email = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($email2). "' AND password = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($password2). "' ");

$num_row = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($num_row>0)
{

     echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success','message'=> 'The group has been removed'));

}else{

     echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success','message'=> 'The group has been removed'));
}

mysql_close($connection);
```

*O que está retornando:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o erro retorna depois do evento submit?

Comment: sim apos eu enviar para os servidor ele retorna esta mensagem, porém eu gostaria que ele retornasse a mensagem do json

Comment: O alert nao resolve objectos, tenta dar console.log :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso tem uma resposta rapida, o alert que foi feito nao resolve o objecto para string, para isso tem que dar `console.log();` para ver a mensagem recebida em objecto
que sera algo assim:

```
[status: 'success', message: 'qll coisa']
```

para aceder a um dos elementos basta isto:

```
data.message
```

Comment: success: function(data){
       console.log(data.message);
      } porém continua retornando os object

Answer (score 0):

Tranforme em JSON:

`alert(JSON.stringify(data));`

`console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`